# Loading dependencies in Roda + Sequel API

Tags: ruby, require, rack, sequel, roda

Recently I've been experimenting with Roda + Sequel. I created simple API that has the following file structure:

```
├── CHANGELOG.md
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── Procfile
├── README.md
├── Rakefile
├── app
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── category.rb
│   │   ├── organization.rb
│   │   └── user.rb
│   ├── schemas
│   │   ├── api
│   │   │   └── v1
│   │   │       ├── login_schema.rb
│   │   │       ├── send_reset_password_instructions_schema.rb
│   │   │       └── update_password_schema.rb
│   │   └── application_schema.rb
│   ├── serializers
│   │   ├── api
│   │   │   └── v1
│   │   │       ├── categories_serializer.rb
│   │   │       ├── login_serializer.rb
│   │   │       └── refresh_token_serializer.rb
│   │   └── application_serializer.rb
│   └── services
│       └── users
│           └── authenticator.rb
├── app.rb
├── bin
│   ├── console
│   └── rake
├── config
│   ├── active_support.rb
│   ├── bcrypt.rb
│   ├── boot.rb
│   ├── database.rb
│   ├── dry_rb.rb
│   ├── environment_variables.rb
│   ├── freeze.rb
│   ├── i18n.rb
│   ├── locales
│   │   ├── errors.pl.yml
│   │   └── pl.yml
│   ├── logger.rb
│   ├── models.rb
│   ├── oj.rb
│   └── puma.rb
├── config.ru
├── db
│   ├── migrate
│   │   ├── 001_enable_uuid_ossp_extension.rb
│   │   ├── 002_create_organizations_table.rb
│   │   ├── 003_drop_organizations_name_unique_index.rb
│   │   ├── 004_create_categories_table.rb
│   │   ├── 005_enable_citext_extension.rb
│   │   ├── 006_create_users_table.rb
│   │   └── 007_add_authentication_token_to_users.rb
│   ├── seeds
│   │   ├── categories.rb
│   │   ├── organizations.rb
│   │   └── users.rb
│   ├── seeds.rb
│   └── structure.sql
├── lib
│   ├── authentication_token_generator.rb
│   ├── authorization_token_validator.rb
│   ├── authorization_tokens_generator.rb
│   ├── constants.rb
│   ├── exceptions.rb
│   ├── message_verifier.rb
│   └── update_password_token_generator.rb
└── spec
    ├── lib
    │   ├── authentication_token_generator_spec.rb
    │   ├── authorization_token_validator_spec.rb
    │   ├── authorization_tokens_generator_spec.rb
    │   ├── constants_spec.rb
    │   ├── message_verifier_spec.rb
    │   └── update_password_token_generator_spec.rb
    ├── models
    │   ├── category_spec.rb
    │   ├── organization_spec.rb
    │   └── user_spec.rb
    ├── requests
    │   ├── api
    │   │   └── v1
    │   │       ├── categories
    │   │       │   └── index_spec.rb
    │   │       ├── login_spec.rb
    │   │       ├── logout_spec.rb
    │   │       ├── refresh_token_spec.rb
    │   │       ├── send_reset_password_instructions_spec.rb
    │   │       └── update_password_spec.rb
    │   └── heartbeat_spec.rb
    ├── schemas
    │   └── api
    │       └── v1
    │           ├── login_schema_spec.rb
    │           ├── send_reset_password_instructions_schema_spec.rb
    │           └── update_password_schema_spec.rb
    ├── services
    │   └── users
    │       └── authenticator_spec.rb
    ├── spec_helper.rb
    └── support
        ├── api_helpers.rb
        └── shared_examples
            └── unauthorized.rb
```

I have the `config/boot.rb` file, which is responsible for loading all of my dependencies:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# This file is responsible for loading all configuration files.

require 'pry'
require 'securerandom'

# Require config files.
require_relative './environment_variables'
require_relative './database'
require_relative './models'
require_relative './i18n'
require_relative './dry_rb'
require_relative './oj'
require_relative './active_support'
require_relative './bcrypt'

# Require all files in lib folder.
require './lib/constants'
require './lib/exceptions'
require './lib/authentication_token_generator'
require './lib/authorization_tokens_generator'
require './lib/authorization_token_validator'
require './lib/update_password_token_generator'
require './lib/message_verifier'

# Require all files in app/models folder.
require './app/models/organization'
require './app/models/category'
require './app/models/user'

# Require all files in app/schemas folder.
require './app/schemas/application_schema'
require './app/schemas/api/v1/login_schema'
require './app/schemas/api/v1/update_password_schema'
require './app/schemas/api/v1/send_reset_password_instructions_schema'

# Require all files in app/services folder.
require './app/services/users/authenticator'

# Require all files in app/serializers folder.
require './app/serializers/application_serializer'
require './app/serializers/api/v1/categories_serializer'
require './app/serializers/api/v1/login_serializer'
require './app/serializers/api/v1/refresh_token_serializer'

require_relative './logger'
require_relative './freeze'
```

Everything is working perfectly fine, but I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing that.

I tried to clean this up using the `Dir` helper method:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# This file is responsible for loading all configuration files.

require 'pry'
require 'securerandom'

# Require config files.
require_relative './environment_variables'
require_relative './database'
require_relative './models'
require_relative './i18n'
require_relative './dry_rb'
require_relative './oj'
require_relative './active_support'
require_relative './bcrypt'


# Require all files in the lib folder.
Dir['./lib/**/**/*.rb'].each { |f| require f }

# Require all files in the app folder.
Dir['./app/**/**/*.rb'].each { |f| require f }

require_relative './logger'
require_relative './freeze'
```

But with that approach, my tests are failing:

```
An error occurred while loading spec_helper.
Failure/Error:
  class LoginSchema < ::ApplicationSchema
    # @!method params
    #   It stores rules for validating POST /api/v1/login endpoint params using dry-validation DSL.
    params do
      required(:email).filled(:string).value(format?: Constants::EMAIL_REGEX)
      required(:password).filled(:string)
    end

NameError:
  uninitialized constant ::ApplicationSchema
# ./app/schemas/api/v1/login_schema.rb:11:in `<module:V1>'
# ./app/schemas/api/v1/login_schema.rb:4:in `<module:Api>'
# ./app/schemas/api/v1/login_schema.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
# ./config/boot.rb:23:in `require'
# ./config/boot.rb:23:in `block in <top (required)>'
# ./config/boot.rb:23:in `each'
# ./config/boot.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
# ./app.rb:5:in `require_relative'
# ./app.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/spec_helper.rb:8:in `require_relative'
# ./spec/spec_helper.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.
No examples found.


Finished in 0.00004 seconds (files took 1.08 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples

Finished in 0.00004 seconds (files took 1.08 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples
```

It seems that tests are failing because `Api::V1::LoginSchema` is required before `ApplicationSchema`.

I will be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Just require the files where they are needed from a dependency perspective. In this case add `require_relative '../../../application_schema'` to the top of the files that need this class. If it has already been "required" then `require` will just return `false` no harm. This will also allow you to unit test in relative isolation where you do not need the entire scope of the application loaded.